# Is thread safety an issue here?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thread-safety

**Context :** I have a service class which has a public `foo` method (which will be called from a rest controller), which in turn will call private `fooHelper` passing a list object which gets populated after few other private method calls in `fooHelper` . The reason for doing this was I wanted to keep the `foo` method short (Please suggest if my approach is wrong for creating private `fooHelper`).

**Question:** Could thread safety be an issue here ? in case multiple threads access `foo` method concurrently (In reference to passed list object) ? I am aware i can use Unmodifiable list but my question is specific to scenario whether current appraoch has thread safety issues ?

I googled and read few articles and as per them this shouldnt be a problem as `foo` is creating `new List` so no threads will share the same list. Is my understanding correct ?

Any help would be hugely appreciated , also excuse me if I have been unable to raise my question clearly. Any edits or suggestions are welcome.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class A {


    @Override
    public List<RoundUpResponse> foo(String token) {

        final List<RoundUpResponse> roundUpResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
        final Accounts accounts = getAccounts(token);
        final List<Account> accountList = accounts.getAccounts();

        accountList.forEach(account -> fooHelper(token, roundUpResponseList, account));
        return roundUpResponseList;
    }

private void fooHelper(String token, List<RoundUpResponse> roundUpResponseList, Account account) {
        final FeedItems transactionFeed = getTransactionFeed(token, account); // private
        final SavingsGoal savingsGoal = getSavingsGoal(token, account); // private
        final Long spareChange = calculateSpareChange(transactionFeed, savingsGoal); // private
        final SavingsGoalTopUp savingsGoalTopUpPayload = createTopUpPayload(account, // privatespareChange);
        final String savingsGoalTransferId = topUpSavingsGoal(token, account, savingsGoal, savingsGoalTopUpPayload); // private
        roundUpResponseList.add(roundUpResponseService.createResponsePerAccount(account, savingsGoal.getName(), savingsGoalTopUpPayload, savingsGoalTransferId)); // private
    }
```

Comment: roundUpResponseList will be different in different threads, so it's safe. You can also consider not passing the list to fooHelper and making it `return roundUpResponseService.createResponsePerAccount(account, savingsGoal.getName(), savingsGoalTopUpPayload, savingsGoalTransferId)`. Then in `foo` you don't need to create the list yourself and do `return accountList.stream().map(account -> fooHelper(token, account)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Thanks Alex , its a great suggestion :)

Comment: Re, "...public foo method...private fooHelper..." Thread safety is never about the methods that the threads call: It always is about the _data_ that they access. Any time you have two or more threads that want to access the same data, and at least one of those threads wants to write it, that's a "thread safety" concern. If two threads call the same method to access different data, then there's no problem. If two threads call the same method (or even if they call _different_ methods) to access the same _data,_ then you have to worry about whether they do it safely.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thanks for the comment, I have edited the question now to make it clearer of my ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code might be thread-safe or not depending on the `getAccounts()` methods. These methods should return defensive copies of the underlying structures of their objects in a thread-safe manner. Then your code will be thread-safe. On the other hand, if, for example, `accounts.getAccounts()` just returns a reference to the internal list of accounts, then another thread may modify the list on the fly while you are iterating through it in your `foo` method. So, make sure that `getAccounts` are safe and then your code is good.

**UPDATE**

Having different calling stacks to getAccounts() has nothing to do with their thread-safety. Here is a *not thread-safe implementation*:

```java
class Accounts {
    private List<Account> accounts;
    public List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

In this case each calling thread will get the same reference to the internal structure, so after you do in your `foo` method

```java
final List<Account> accountList = accounts.getAccounts();
```

in thread1, some thread2 can modify the accountList and it can break the iteration over this list in `foo`. You should create defensive copy, for example:

```java
class Accounts {
    private List<Account> accounts;
    public List<Account> getAccounts() {        
        synchronized(this) {  
          return new ArrayList<>(accounts);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `synchronized` and returning a reference to the copy of the list, which we make in a hopefully thread-safe manner ("hopefully", because we must be sure that all modifications of the `accounts` are `synchronized` on the same object as well).

In your implementation you obtain the list by performing a REST API call, which should return a new list for each call, independent of the other. So your implementation is safe.

Comment: thanks ! I think i understand your point but wouldn’t the other invoking thread have their own stack for getAccounts() invocation ? Below is how ```getAcoounts()``` is implemented.
```private Accounts getAccounts(String token) {
        return externalAdapter.getAccount(token); // rest Api call to external partner
    }```